# python object is not iterable or subscriptable

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have c++ code wrapped up with cython to be used from python.

Demo example

Foopxd.pxd

```
cdef extern from "Foos.hpp":
    cdef cppclass Foos
```

Foopyx.pyx

```
cdef class Pyfoos:
    cdef Foos thisobj

def get_foos(pattern):
    cdef Foos foox
    foox = Foopxd.get_foos(pattern)
    fooy = Pyfoos()
    fooy.thisobj = foox
    return fooy
```

The function `get_foo` return a class object both in cpp or python. The returned object is of type `Foos` which a collection of objects of type `Foo`. I can store the returned value in a variable `A` of type `Pyfoos()`. However, I cannot iterate through individual `foo` from the object `foos` in python. I can however access

```
A = get_foos("*")
A[5]
```

or

```
for(auto x:A){print x;}
```

from c++

I want to add what is needed in python to make a class iterable or subscriptable.

Note: I know `get_foos()` returns a object of type `Foos()` which is a collection `Foo`'s but don't know whether I have accurately represented that here. Also, I have no access to the cpp functions but can guarantee `get_foos()` will return the correct object[which is a collection of object]. However, I do not know the structure of packed object `Foos`.

python

```
>> import foo
>> A = Pyfoos()
>> A = get_foos("*")
>> A[2]
TypeError: "Foos" object is not subscriptable
>> for x in A:
...    print(x)
...
TypeError: "Foos" object is not iterable
```

Given that I have no control over the cpp/hpp files. But I get the object from them. What can I do to make them iterable in a for loop or directly subscriptable?

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: 'Foopxd.Pyfoos' object is not iterable
```

I would want to call `x.bar` attribute for each `foo` in `foos`.

Comment: This clearly isn't a [mcve]. Why would you get `TypeError: "Foo" object is not subscriptable` when your code does not contain a type called `Foo`?

Comment: OK. But there's still the basic problem: you have a function called `Foopxd.get_foos` that we know nothing about but it appears to return a `Foos` by value. We know almost nothing about `Foos`, except that it might be a container for a different class (`foo`?) and somehow we're expected to know how to iterate over this mystery container. On top of that your edit still doesn't show the error that your Python code would produce. This is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

In brief: you need to implement either `__iter__` (to create a Python iterable) or `__getitem__` and `__len__` for `Pyfoos`. You don't need to do both.

You have not provided sufficient detail about your C++ interface to know exactly what it is, so I've taken a guess. The example I've provided works on its own, however it may not match your real interface exactly. This is your problem... What we do know about your C++ interface is that `Foos`:

- Has an `operator[]` which probably returns a `Foo&`. (We know this because you claim to be able to do `A[0]`)
- Has a `begin` and `end` function returning some iterator type. (We know this because you claim to be able to use it in `for (auto x: A)` style loops). Unfortunately `auto` doesn't work with Cython so I've assumed the type is called `FooIter`.

I've also assumed that `Foos` has a member function `size_t size()`

For the sake of creating a quick test case I've created the following c++ file. I've used a typedef for `vector` to save time because it exposes exactly the right interface.:

```
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(int v): val(v) {}
    int bar() { return val; }
private:
    int val;
};

typedef std::vector<Foo> Foos;
typedef Foos::iterator FooIter;

inline Foos get_foos() {
    return Foos{ Foo(1), Foo(2), Foo(3) };
}
```

We then expose the relevant parts of this interface to Cython

```
#cython: language=c++
# distutils: include_dirs=<some path>

from cython.operator import dereference, preincrement
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef extern from "cpp_interface.hpp":
    cdef cppclass Foo:
        int bar()

    cdef cppclass FooIter:
        Foo& operator*()
        bool operator==(const FooIter&)
        FooIter operator++()

    cdef cppclass Foos:
        FooIter begin()
        FooIter end()
        Foo& operator[](size_t n)
        size_t size()

    Foos get_foos()
```

We then create a Python wrapper for `Foo`. This holds a pointer, but doesn't actually own the object. Instead it has a reference to the Python object that does own the `Foo` (probably a `PyFoos`) to ensure that it is kept alive appropriately:

```
cdef class PyFoo:
    cdef Foo* thisptr
    cdef object owner
    def bar(self):
        return self.thisptr.bar()
```

We then create `PyFoos`, the container wrapper:

```
cdef class Pyfoos:
    cdef Foos thisobj

def py_get_foos():
    cdef Foos foox = get_foos()
    cdef Pyfoos fooy = Pyfoos()
    fooy.thisobj = foox # note this is copied, not moved. This may be expensive
    return fooy
```

To implement the `__getitem__`/`__len__` interface you just use the C++ `operator[]` and `size()`:

```
# add this to `PyFoos`:

def __len__(self):
    return self.thisobj.size()
def __getitem__(self,int n):
    if n>=self.thisobj.size():
        raise IndexError()
    cdef Foo* f = &self.thisobj[n]
    py_f = PyFoo()
    py_f.thisptr = f
    py_f.owner = self # ensure that a reference to self is kept while py_f exists
    return py_f
```

If you want to implement the `__iter__` interface instead then you create an iterator class. This class adopts the same approach to ownership as `PyFoo` (i.e. it keeps a reference to ensure that the `Pyfoos` object stays alive). It uses the `begin()` and `end()` functions of `Foos` to get an iterator and then increments that iterator until it reaches `end()`. `dereference` does `*iter` which gets a reference to the `Foo` the iterator points to.

```
cdef class PyFooIter:
    cdef FooIter i
    cdef FooIter end
    cdef object owner

    def __init__(self, Pyfoos foos):
        self.i = foos.thisobj.begin()
        self.end = foos.thisobj.end()
        self.owner = foos # ensure foos is kept alive until we are done

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        cdef Foo* f
        if self.i==self.end:
            raise StopIteration()
        f = &dereference(self.i)
        py_f = PyFoo()
        py_f.thisptr = f
        py_f.owner = self

        preincrement(self.i) # ++(self.i)
        return py_f
```

You also need to add the following code to `Pyfoos`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return PyFooIter(self)
```

---

These can be tested with

```
for f in PyFooWrapper.py_get_foos():
    print(f.bar())
```

which prints 1 2 3 (on separate lines) as expected.